# Angular - how to filter sorted arrays efficiently?

Tags: angularjs

I have a sorted array of possible times in a day, from 00:00 to 23:59, which has 720 elements in total, so it can be quite big.

What would be the best way, regarding performance, to display only times after (or before) a certain, specified time? A simple filter would perform the check for all elements in the array, not considering the fact, that the times are sorted already.

Is there any method, that would perform faster than the example below?

```
<div ng-repeat="time in times" ng-if="timeAfter(time, specifiedTime)">
    {{time}}
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you should consider doing something server side instead of client side since its an "intensive task"

Comment: `ng-if` is a poor choice since it will create needless watchers. Use a custom filter or filter the array in controller before passing to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using binary search on a parallel array with numerical values of the times to find the starting index, then splitting the array before displaying.

I used lodash library for the binary search. `timeminutes` is an array containing the times in integer format as minutes since the start of the day (`hours * 60 + minutes`), in the same order as `times`.

I have provided a simplified example of what I did

```
var timeToMinutes = function(time) {
    var selectedTimedata = time.split(":");
    return selectedTimedata[0] * 60 + parseInt(selectedTimedata[1], 10);
};

// The following arrays are created using simple iteration, but simplified for this example
var times = ["0:00", "0:01", "0:02"]; //...and so on
var timeminutes = [0, 1, 2];

var start = !$scope.startTime ? 0 : _.sortedIndexOf(timeminutes, timeToMinutes($scope.startTime));
var end = !$scope.endTime ? timeminutes.length : (_.sortedIndexOf(timeminutes, timeToMinutes($scope.endTime)) + 1);                        
$scope.times = times.slice(start, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the best performance I'd suggest not to use ng-repeat on the whole array. You should create a service/factory (lets say "timesFilterProvider") that will receive the minimal time and return only the matching times. 
It may use a bubble sort or any other sorting algorithm to find the minimal time and return the rest of the array.

If you use ng-filter or ng-if you will have to scan the entire array so don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The angular `filter` is designed for this, and `ng-if` has potential impact due to the re-rendering of the DOM that may be undesirable.

Try:

```
<div ng-repeat="time in times | filter: timeAfter(time, specifiedTime)">
   {{time}}
</div>
```

However, that won't solve the root problem of having such a large array.  It would be best to reduce the array before it makes it to the ng-repeat, as mentioned in [Dennis Nerush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35628527/664342)

Comment: Last part doesn't make really sense. The filter will reduce the array size being passed to ng-repeat

Comment: @charlietfl Its my understanding that the filter gets re-applied every digest cycle, so if you're filtering a large array, and triggering digest cycles where the filtered value isn't actually changed, it can be less efficient than shrinking the array before sending it to the ng-repeat.

Comment: Ok.. that's true. Filtering of array itself though will be huge improvement over what OP currently has. 720 items isn't huge

Comment: Yeah, 720 isn't bad, but my answer felt incomplete with just the filter suggestion.  Maybe it wasn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your question depends on: **"Is your Filtered/Sorted list mutable?"**

- Every directive (like ngIf, ngRepeat), or filter, will be ran on each $digestLoop, so, there aren't way to have good performances if your data is mutable...
- Using `track by` increments perfomances

But, if your list is immutable, you can serve it *as already filtered list* and tell angular to print it via *"one-time binding"*.

example:

```js
function ListCtrl($scope, ListData, MINIMUM_VISIBLE_DATA) {
  var vm = $scope;
  
  vm.items = ListData.filter(function(item) {
    console.log(new Date(item.date) >= MINIMUM_VISIBLE_DATA, item)
    
    return new Date(item.date) >= MINIMUM_VISIBLE_DATA;
  });
  
  vm.rule = MINIMUM_VISIBLE_DATA;
  vm.length =  vm.items.length + '/' + ListData.length;
}


angular
  .module('testApp', [])
  .controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'ListData', 'MINIMUM_VISIBLE_DATA', ListCtrl])
  .value('MINIMUM_VISIBLE_DATA', new Date())
  .value('ListData', [{"id":1,"date":"2014-08-12T11:50:42Z"},
{"id":2,"date":"2013-12-19T08:35:42Z"},
{"id":3,"date":"2013-11-24T14:35:20Z"},
{"id":4,"date":"2016-10-26T20:18:59Z"},
{"id":5,"date":"2013-08-13T19:11:11Z"},
{"id":6,"date":"2014-11-28T12:08:23Z"},
{"id":7,"date":"2014-07-28T14:56:34Z"},
{"id":8,"date":"2013-04-14T21:12:55Z"},
{"id":9,"date":"2016-02-29T02:13:58Z"},
{"id":10,"date":"2016-02-06T09:29:34Z"},
{"id":11,"date":"2015-12-20T02:18:47Z"},
{"id":12,"date":"2016-08-17T23:17:46Z"},
{"id":13,"date":"2016-05-01T23:02:59Z"},
{"id":14,"date":"2016-09-26T08:54:42Z"},
{"id":15,"date":"2015-09-14T16:27:25Z"},
{"id":16,"date":"2014-10-30T05:35:45Z"},
{"id":17,"date":"2013-12-18T05:30:17Z"},
{"id":18,"date":"2015-08-01T06:59:31Z"},
{"id":19,"date":"2014-08-26T15:57:11Z"},
{"id":20,"date":"2016-12-01T09:09:11Z"},
{"id":21,"date":"2016-05-03T13:21:00Z"},
{"id":22,"date":"2015-10-27T02:26:22Z"},
{"id":23,"date":"2013-07-04T21:54:06Z"},
{"id":24,"date":"2015-11-13T07:07:16Z"},
{"id":25,"date":"2014-12-19T12:27:58Z"},
{"id":26,"date":"2016-07-31T21:33:32Z"},
{"id":27,"date":"2013-08-21T08:54:43Z"},
{"id":28,"date":"2013-10-12T08:25:02Z"},
{"id":29,"date":"2015-09-30T20:09:52Z"},
{"id":30,"date":"2014-06-26T00:57:30Z"},
{"id":31,"date":"2014-05-25T16:15:56Z"},
{"id":32,"date":"2014-09-13T08:19:49Z"},
{"id":33,"date":"2013-08-04T08:00:55Z"},
{"id":34,"date":"2015-02-24T09:54:18Z"},
{"id":35,"date":"2014-09-06T23:28:36Z"},
{"id":36,"date":"2013-11-12T17:29:54Z"},
{"id":37,"date":"2016-11-06T10:56:33Z"},
{"id":38,"date":"2016-09-25T06:05:24Z"},
{"id":39,"date":"2015-04-12T21:54:16Z"},
{"id":40,"date":"2015-03-22T02:06:37Z"},
{"id":41,"date":"2015-02-01T16:56:06Z"},
{"id":42,"date":"2013-10-24T06:58:42Z"},
{"id":43,"date":"2015-06-16T16:14:06Z"},
{"id":44,"date":"2016-09-25T07:20:03Z"},
{"id":45,"date":"2014-06-11T13:32:36Z"},
{"id":46,"date":"2015-07-30T02:53:28Z"},
{"id":47,"date":"2015-10-08T13:43:18Z"},
{"id":48,"date":"2016-01-08T14:19:59Z"},
{"id":49,"date":"2013-05-28T00:00:51Z"},
{"id":50,"date":"2016-05-20T11:02:26Z"},
{"id":51,"date":"2014-05-12T03:05:02Z"},
{"id":52,"date":"2013-10-22T04:29:57Z"},
{"id":53,"date":"2015-06-01T21:22:15Z"},
{"id":54,"date":"2015-02-25T02:54:36Z"},
{"id":55,"date":"2016-10-24T16:52:01Z"},
{"id":56,"date":"2015-02-06T15:32:43Z"},
{"id":57,"date":"2013-10-19T19:34:14Z"},
{"id":58,"date":"2014-09-13T09:52:34Z"},
{"id":59,"date":"2013-11-05T23:04:04Z"},
{"id":60,"date":"2014-06-20T07:44:36Z"},
{"id":61,"date":"2014-04-24T10:33:03Z"},
{"id":62,"date":"2016-06-20T07:13:06Z"},
{"id":63,"date":"2014-06-14T13:08:50Z"},
{"id":64,"date":"2015-08-16T02:35:52Z"},
{"id":65,"date":"2014-07-04T10:15:12Z"},
{"id":66,"date":"2014-05-06T16:58:07Z"},
{"id":67,"date":"2014-12-11T07:19:12Z"},
{"id":68,"date":"2015-09-28T02:27:31Z"},
{"id":69,"date":"2016-04-25T19:11:41Z"},
{"id":70,"date":"2016-01-01T23:35:37Z"},
{"id":71,"date":"2013-08-11T18:40:23Z"},
{"id":72,"date":"2015-02-22T03:11:37Z"},
{"id":73,"date":"2013-09-15T13:46:19Z"},
{"id":74,"date":"2014-02-15T21:50:25Z"},
{"id":75,"date":"2013-01-27T19:27:04Z"},
{"id":76,"date":"2015-07-22T10:50:53Z"},
{"id":77,"date":"2013-02-22T22:26:14Z"},
{"id":78,"date":"2013-03-28T07:17:34Z"},
{"id":79,"date":"2013-07-05T03:21:54Z"},
{"id":80,"date":"2013-04-20T13:58:38Z"},
{"id":81,"date":"2013-06-09T06:10:06Z"},
{"id":82,"date":"2015-01-30T20:20:56Z"},
{"id":83,"date":"2013-03-07T08:57:22Z"},
{"id":84,"date":"2014-02-15T06:46:32Z"},
{"id":85,"date":"2015-04-25T01:11:15Z"},
{"id":86,"date":"2016-07-29T17:55:34Z"},
{"id":87,"date":"2016-08-30T11:21:21Z"},
{"id":88,"date":"2013-08-25T15:26:28Z"},
{"id":89,"date":"2014-10-31T22:23:55Z"},
{"id":90,"date":"2016-03-19T17:28:54Z"},
{"id":91,"date":"2016-05-11T07:29:31Z"},
{"id":92,"date":"2014-05-01T07:21:36Z"},
{"id":93,"date":"2014-04-13T06:14:20Z"},
{"id":94,"date":"2014-04-06T15:22:26Z"},
{"id":95,"date":"2016-06-15T14:16:36Z"},
{"id":96,"date":"2014-07-26T14:35:51Z"},
{"id":97,"date":"2015-10-22T14:29:10Z"},
{"id":98,"date":"2016-07-22T23:57:09Z"},
{"id":99,"date":"2015-04-24T13:39:33Z"},
{"id":100,"date":"2014-07-17T08:39:27Z"},
{"id":101,"date":"2015-12-18T16:57:51Z"},
{"id":102,"date":"2014-05-06T10:16:01Z"},
{"id":103,"date":"2016-11-06T21:13:59Z"},
{"id":104,"date":"2014-02-15T11:24:58Z"},
{"id":105,"date":"2014-09-13T17:11:01Z"},
{"id":106,"date":"2015-12-04T16:34:31Z"},
{"id":107,"date":"2016-04-11T21:44:49Z"},
{"id":108,"date":"2014-07-06T07:40:35Z"},
{"id":109,"date":"2016-11-24T20:59:52Z"},
{"id":110,"date":"2015-11-18T07:12:07Z"},
{"id":111,"date":"2015-05-26T00:29:31Z"},
{"id":112,"date":"2015-01-29T10:45:47Z"},
{"id":113,"date":"2014-12-25T08:46:48Z"},
{"id":114,"date":"2014-09-27T16:15:17Z"},
{"id":115,"date":"2013-12-17T23:47:24Z"},
{"id":116,"date":"2015-11-01T18:03:05Z"},
{"id":117,"date":"2016-05-26T11:59:22Z"},
{"id":118,"date":"2016-11-13T03:40:51Z"},
{"id":119,"date":"2016-11-10T19:33:42Z"},
{"id":120,"date":"2013-09-11T13:43:49Z"},
{"id":121,"date":"2016-02-09T02:26:18Z"},
{"id":122,"date":"2014-08-15T18:40:20Z"},
{"id":123,"date":"2015-11-20T07:12:45Z"},
{"id":124,"date":"2013-01-31T21:56:57Z"},
{"id":125,"date":"2015-07-26T23:20:48Z"},
{"id":126,"date":"2015-10-29T00:58:45Z"},
{"id":127,"date":"2016-11-27T11:44:10Z"},
{"id":128,"date":"2013-02-09T18:38:34Z"},
{"id":129,"date":"2016-04-07T18:02:38Z"},
{"id":130,"date":"2014-08-25T14:37:46Z"},
{"id":131,"date":"2015-10-27T21:17:50Z"},
{"id":132,"date":"2013-09-07T03:11:27Z"},
{"id":133,"date":"2015-01-28T08:46:03Z"},
{"id":134,"date":"2014-07-16T12:15:08Z"},
{"id":135,"date":"2016-11-08T01:35:50Z"},
{"id":136,"date":"2014-01-08T20:04:17Z"},
{"id":137,"date":"2014-06-18T00:29:40Z"},
{"id":138,"date":"2016-11-20T16:27:57Z"},
{"id":139,"date":"2016-10-04T22:54:24Z"},
{"id":140,"date":"2016-12-23T11:21:06Z"},
{"id":141,"date":"2016-08-15T18:37:36Z"},
{"id":142,"date":"2013-09-15T21:48:01Z"},
{"id":143,"date":"2014-08-11T06:15:00Z"},
{"id":144,"date":"2014-02-01T12:07:07Z"},
{"id":145,"date":"2016-09-22T10:38:11Z"},
{"id":146,"date":"2016-04-28T01:31:32Z"},
{"id":147,"date":"2013-11-09T13:04:56Z"},
{"id":148,"date":"2014-10-06T01:57:41Z"},
{"id":149,"date":"2015-08-13T17:30:12Z"},
{"id":150,"date":"2013-01-29T09:30:16Z"},
{"id":151,"date":"2015-10-04T18:59:36Z"},
{"id":152,"date":"2014-08-01T16:36:48Z"},
{"id":153,"date":"2014-09-28T03:23:45Z"},
{"id":154,"date":"2015-01-19T21:32:44Z"},
{"id":155,"date":"2016-11-16T21:03:39Z"},
{"id":156,"date":"2014-03-17T04:35:12Z"},
{"id":157,"date":"2015-06-24T12:37:11Z"},
{"id":158,"date":"2013-10-23T09:56:53Z"},
{"id":159,"date":"2014-03-04T10:48:53Z"},
{"id":160,"date":"2014-12-06T08:59:42Z"},
{"id":161,"date":"2016-09-27T11:00:56Z"},
{"id":162,"date":"2014-02-03T09:17:22Z"},
{"id":163,"date":"2016-04-07T19:49:33Z"},
{"id":164,"date":"2014-02-08T12:56:11Z"},
{"id":165,"date":"2014-09-20T12:56:43Z"},
{"id":166,"date":"2013-08-22T12:17:10Z"},
{"id":167,"date":"2013-07-31T20:24:46Z"},
{"id":168,"date":"2015-05-12T06:34:38Z"},
{"id":169,"date":"2013-02-05T03:32:51Z"},
{"id":170,"date":"2015-05-27T08:31:00Z"},
{"id":171,"date":"2015-04-07T13:27:28Z"},
{"id":172,"date":"2013-10-10T13:25:28Z"},
{"id":173,"date":"2015-06-08T12:19:30Z"},
{"id":174,"date":"2014-11-27T02:12:16Z"},
{"id":175,"date":"2013-06-28T13:48:19Z"},
{"id":176,"date":"2016-09-12T23:01:26Z"},
{"id":177,"date":"2013-10-21T07:10:50Z"},
{"id":178,"date":"2016-08-20T14:25:40Z"},
{"id":179,"date":"2015-06-27T00:45:39Z"},
{"id":180,"date":"2016-09-23T10:24:49Z"},
{"id":181,"date":"2014-09-28T21:10:15Z"},
{"id":182,"date":"2014-07-27T09:43:20Z"},
{"id":183,"date":"2014-06-16T10:01:36Z"},
{"id":184,"date":"2014-02-13T17:58:05Z"},
{"id":185,"date":"2015-08-15T13:33:51Z"},
{"id":186,"date":"2014-02-06T18:55:38Z"},
{"id":187,"date":"2013-12-23T02:40:38Z"},
{"id":188,"date":"2014-04-10T06:04:15Z"},
{"id":189,"date":"2013-08-16T08:02:53Z"},
{"id":190,"date":"2013-06-18T15:24:29Z"},
{"id":191,"date":"2016-11-26T11:37:29Z"},
{"id":192,"date":"2015-08-18T10:30:24Z"},
{"id":193,"date":"2014-11-22T10:10:07Z"},
{"id":194,"date":"2015-10-13T16:18:31Z"},
{"id":195,"date":"2013-08-13T22:28:43Z"},
{"id":196,"date":"2013-04-19T00:14:22Z"},
{"id":197,"date":"2016-10-06T06:52:47Z"},
{"id":198,"date":"2016-12-21T21:13:12Z"},
{"id":199,"date":"2016-10-25T00:13:37Z"},
{"id":200,"date":"2013-05-04T09:04:51Z"},
{"id":201,"date":"2015-08-08T22:12:02Z"},
{"id":202,"date":"2015-01-04T03:07:02Z"},
{"id":203,"date":"2016-06-15T02:39:45Z"},
{"id":204,"date":"2014-08-16T03:57:39Z"},
{"id":205,"date":"2016-03-01T00:21:07Z"},
{"id":206,"date":"2016-07-05T18:37:52Z"},
{"id":207,"date":"2014-07-19T10:04:15Z"},
{"id":208,"date":"2014-12-13T14:44:15Z"},
{"id":209,"date":"2013-01-23T23:03:32Z"},
{"id":210,"date":"2013-02-28T11:49:23Z"},
{"id":211,"date":"2013-07-06T16:12:59Z"},
{"id":212,"date":"2014-06-27T03:27:27Z"},
{"id":213,"date":"2015-05-12T11:10:17Z"},
{"id":214,"date":"2014-04-05T15:18:40Z"},
{"id":215,"date":"2016-09-10T08:20:58Z"},
{"id":216,"date":"2016-06-02T16:14:35Z"},
{"id":217,"date":"2013-04-18T22:37:46Z"},
{"id":218,"date":"2015-07-13T03:04:27Z"},
{"id":219,"date":"2014-04-04T07:46:51Z"},
{"id":220,"date":"2013-02-06T09:47:12Z"},
{"id":221,"date":"2013-10-07T17:38:21Z"},
{"id":222,"date":"2015-01-18T06:51:15Z"},
{"id":223,"date":"2013-02-09T18:54:07Z"},
{"id":224,"date":"2014-02-21T12:20:46Z"},
{"id":225,"date":"2015-09-07T19:45:11Z"},
{"id":226,"date":"2014-01-14T12:56:41Z"},
{"id":227,"date":"2015-06-07T07:01:52Z"},
{"id":228,"date":"2013-07-07T04:35:19Z"},
{"id":229,"date":"2016-07-10T10:12:51Z"},
{"id":230,"date":"2016-07-13T14:24:12Z"},
{"id":231,"date":"2016-10-14T07:08:41Z"},
{"id":232,"date":"2016-06-17T06:32:38Z"},
{"id":233,"date":"2016-07-07T21:54:06Z"},
{"id":234,"date":"2016-03-10T21:19:09Z"},
{"id":235,"date":"2013-02-09T02:55:50Z"},
{"id":236,"date":"2016-04-17T10:23:37Z"},
{"id":237,"date":"2014-09-16T09:54:15Z"},
{"id":238,"date":"2014-11-17T16:47:48Z"},
{"id":239,"date":"2015-08-26T06:28:07Z"},
{"id":240,"date":"2013-03-14T14:54:25Z"},
{"id":241,"date":"2015-01-06T07:27:09Z"},
{"id":242,"date":"2015-09-03T18:35:05Z"},
{"id":243,"date":"2014-06-27T01:46:29Z"},
{"id":244,"date":"2016-08-18T12:22:28Z"},
{"id":245,"date":"2015-12-24T00:18:42Z"},
{"id":246,"date":"2015-07-23T16:21:47Z"},
{"id":247,"date":"2016-09-26T18:20:06Z"},
{"id":248,"date":"2016-11-05T02:10:38Z"},
{"id":249,"date":"2013-10-13T21:43:03Z"},
{"id":250,"date":"2016-03-04T10:09:09Z"},
{"id":251,"date":"2013-10-07T06:46:56Z"},
{"id":252,"date":"2013-01-31T11:21:19Z"},
{"id":253,"date":"2016-05-28T05:48:18Z"},
{"id":254,"date":"2013-02-25T06:16:42Z"},
{"id":255,"date":"2016-07-30T18:53:20Z"},
{"id":256,"date":"2016-11-11T16:42:45Z"},
{"id":257,"date":"2015-12-23T16:01:23Z"},
{"id":258,"date":"2013-09-19T14:26:23Z"},
{"id":259,"date":"2015-01-06T06:24:55Z"},
{"id":260,"date":"2014-03-20T15:33:25Z"},
{"id":261,"date":"2013-02-19T13:18:15Z"},
{"id":262,"date":"2015-01-15T06:30:10Z"},
{"id":263,"date":"2013-04-29T09:20:39Z"},
{"id":264,"date":"2014-01-07T05:03:48Z"},
{"id":265,"date":"2016-06-30T09:23:03Z"},
{"id":266,"date":"2013-01-09T09:42:12Z"},
{"id":267,"date":"2013-06-16T23:15:26Z"},
{"id":268,"date":"2015-09-22T07:09:36Z"},
{"id":269,"date":"2016-10-10T04:45:08Z"},
{"id":270,"date":"2013-02-06T23:44:38Z"},
{"id":271,"date":"2013-12-12T10:58:34Z"},
{"id":272,"date":"2013-04-06T00:19:50Z"},
{"id":273,"date":"2014-10-18T13:10:00Z"},
{"id":274,"date":"2016-11-19T20:24:37Z"},
{"id":275,"date":"2014-04-20T00:28:21Z"},
{"id":276,"date":"2016-02-23T05:50:19Z"},
{"id":277,"date":"2016-06-11T22:00:01Z"},
{"id":278,"date":"2016-08-06T06:08:23Z"},
{"id":279,"date":"2014-06-21T17:27:53Z"},
{"id":280,"date":"2016-08-13T13:48:15Z"},
{"id":281,"date":"2016-08-26T17:51:15Z"},
{"id":282,"date":"2013-08-14T14:21:40Z"},
{"id":283,"date":"2013-03-21T11:34:21Z"},
{"id":284,"date":"2016-06-18T20:46:33Z"},
{"id":285,"date":"2014-04-13T02:21:48Z"},
{"id":286,"date":"2015-09-13T20:05:08Z"},
{"id":287,"date":"2016-06-01T01:08:25Z"},
{"id":288,"date":"2014-10-10T18:53:49Z"},
{"id":289,"date":"2015-02-08T07:51:34Z"},
{"id":290,"date":"2015-01-13T21:37:14Z"},
{"id":291,"date":"2013-10-04T19:23:03Z"},
{"id":292,"date":"2014-10-07T00:07:10Z"},
{"id":293,"date":"2015-01-18T20:51:16Z"},
{"id":294,"date":"2014-05-12T03:51:10Z"},
{"id":295,"date":"2014-06-02T08:39:40Z"},
{"id":296,"date":"2014-09-14T08:47:36Z"},
{"id":297,"date":"2016-05-03T02:02:32Z"},
{"id":298,"date":"2016-07-11T06:33:54Z"},
{"id":299,"date":"2013-01-06T04:42:05Z"},
{"id":300,"date":"2013-03-17T20:28:31Z"},
{"id":301,"date":"2016-01-12T23:19:55Z"},
{"id":302,"date":"2013-05-01T04:38:35Z"},
{"id":303,"date":"2014-08-11T20:32:41Z"},
{"id":304,"date":"2016-12-01T08:04:11Z"},
{"id":305,"date":"2015-03-05T05:53:54Z"},
{"id":306,"date":"2014-03-23T04:41:25Z"},
{"id":307,"date":"2013-06-23T18:14:18Z"},
{"id":308,"date":"2016-03-18T16:27:03Z"},
{"id":309,"date":"2014-04-21T07:38:06Z"},
{"id":310,"date":"2016-11-28T19:53:08Z"},
{"id":311,"date":"2013-01-07T02:24:16Z"},
{"id":312,"date":"2016-07-06T17:05:28Z"},
{"id":313,"date":"2013-08-19T13:28:12Z"},
{"id":314,"date":"2014-03-02T01:32:14Z"},
{"id":315,"date":"2015-12-04T10:51:51Z"},
{"id":316,"date":"2014-10-30T18:59:24Z"},
{"id":317,"date":"2016-09-09T23:44:48Z"},
{"id":318,"date":"2013-10-11T02:32:09Z"},
{"id":319,"date":"2016-08-22T00:24:49Z"},
{"id":320,"date":"2016-08-31T03:52:46Z"},
{"id":321,"date":"2014-10-16T20:08:22Z"},
{"id":322,"date":"2014-05-01T09:18:52Z"},
{"id":323,"date":"2013-12-04T10:59:18Z"},
{"id":324,"date":"2013-12-18T22:51:04Z"},
{"id":325,"date":"2016-11-08T12:33:34Z"},
{"id":326,"date":"2013-06-16T20:26:29Z"},
{"id":327,"date":"2014-05-18T13:32:41Z"},
{"id":328,"date":"2016-05-10T20:53:25Z"},
{"id":329,"date":"2013-03-24T10:17:02Z"},
{"id":330,"date":"2016-09-05T06:05:48Z"},
{"id":331,"date":"2016-12-01T08:10:24Z"},
{"id":332,"date":"2015-03-25T18:08:38Z"},
{"id":333,"date":"2014-08-23T20:48:41Z"},
{"id":334,"date":"2016-04-01T14:25:16Z"},
{"id":335,"date":"2013-05-04T21:28:33Z"},
{"id":336,"date":"2015-06-26T21:17:26Z"},
{"id":337,"date":"2013-07-20T03:39:13Z"},
{"id":338,"date":"2015-03-10T06:38:20Z"},
{"id":339,"date":"2013-08-02T03:23:20Z"},
{"id":340,"date":"2016-05-27T04:34:38Z"},
{"id":341,"date":"2015-12-09T21:31:23Z"},
{"id":342,"date":"2013-07-28T22:38:13Z"},
{"id":343,"date":"2014-12-17T17:55:02Z"},
{"id":344,"date":"2015-05-04T15:27:24Z"},
{"id":345,"date":"2016-07-02T01:04:16Z"},
{"id":346,"date":"2014-11-22T18:16:28Z"},
{"id":347,"date":"2015-08-11T22:03:05Z"},
{"id":348,"date":"2013-05-01T17:52:34Z"},
{"id":349,"date":"2016-09-24T19:17:21Z"},
{"id":350,"date":"2014-03-12T18:24:36Z"},
{"id":351,"date":"2014-02-04T20:19:47Z"},
{"id":352,"date":"2016-10-25T18:27:00Z"},
{"id":353,"date":"2015-07-10T04:45:12Z"},
{"id":354,"date":"2015-02-24T07:33:17Z"},
{"id":355,"date":"2016-12-13T23:59:39Z"},
{"id":356,"date":"2013-09-13T07:08:12Z"},
{"id":357,"date":"2015-12-11T11:42:32Z"},
{"id":358,"date":"2016-02-05T13:29:54Z"},
{"id":359,"date":"2014-09-07T13:55:07Z"},
{"id":360,"date":"2016-05-06T14:33:04Z"},
{"id":361,"date":"2016-03-04T16:31:17Z"},
{"id":362,"date":"2016-02-17T02:37:31Z"},
{"id":363,"date":"2015-01-23T23:59:59Z"},
{"id":364,"date":"2014-04-30T00:38:57Z"},
{"id":365,"date":"2013-02-20T19:43:05Z"},
{"id":366,"date":"2016-02-19T11:45:38Z"},
{"id":367,"date":"2014-07-09T10:37:01Z"},
{"id":368,"date":"2013-04-19T22:11:54Z"},
{"id":369,"date":"2014-11-29T16:29:06Z"},
{"id":370,"date":"2014-11-12T18:31:35Z"},
{"id":371,"date":"2016-05-20T11:53:58Z"},
{"id":372,"date":"2015-03-02T16:01:13Z"},
{"id":373,"date":"2013-05-25T04:55:19Z"},
{"id":374,"date":"2013-10-03T21:52:13Z"},
{"id":375,"date":"2015-12-24T02:53:35Z"},
{"id":376,"date":"2015-05-16T08:31:15Z"},
{"id":377,"date":"2015-05-30T11:49:39Z"},
{"id":378,"date":"2013-02-16T10:44:30Z"},
{"id":379,"date":"2014-06-17T19:44:53Z"},
{"id":380,"date":"2014-10-02T07:12:53Z"},
{"id":381,"date":"2014-05-07T15:34:58Z"},
{"id":382,"date":"2013-12-17T04:31:59Z"},
{"id":383,"date":"2016-09-25T23:13:35Z"},
{"id":384,"date":"2015-03-27T05:39:31Z"},
{"id":385,"date":"2016-05-08T10:03:11Z"},
{"id":386,"date":"2015-06-14T21:30:07Z"},
{"id":387,"date":"2015-01-03T22:41:58Z"},
{"id":388,"date":"2016-08-07T13:44:11Z"},
{"id":389,"date":"2016-01-05T06:39:10Z"},
{"id":390,"date":"2015-10-25T05:59:12Z"},
{"id":391,"date":"2014-09-28T07:37:20Z"},
{"id":392,"date":"2014-07-21T06:40:45Z"},
{"id":393,"date":"2016-05-05T00:47:39Z"},
{"id":394,"date":"2013-01-05T05:01:57Z"},
{"id":395,"date":"2014-12-22T23:47:12Z"},
{"id":396,"date":"2014-11-13T20:37:08Z"},
{"id":397,"date":"2013-01-26T09:32:33Z"},
{"id":398,"date":"2015-03-25T13:39:28Z"},
{"id":399,"date":"2015-05-20T04:59:42Z"},
{"id":400,"date":"2014-11-24T20:30:38Z"},
{"id":401,"date":"2013-10-31T07:52:22Z"},
{"id":402,"date":"2015-10-14T15:19:55Z"},
{"id":403,"date":"2013-02-08T12:03:37Z"},
{"id":404,"date":"2013-12-24T20:39:50Z"},
{"id":405,"date":"2013-06-24T17:57:49Z"},
{"id":406,"date":"2014-08-14T15:16:16Z"},
{"id":407,"date":"2014-12-16T15:51:26Z"},
{"id":408,"date":"2013-07-13T20:41:51Z"},
{"id":409,"date":"2015-03-02T20:50:32Z"},
{"id":410,"date":"2016-10-04T17:31:17Z"},
{"id":411,"date":"2014-05-05T00:24:51Z"},
{"id":412,"date":"2015-04-21T22:57:26Z"},
{"id":413,"date":"2015-04-22T18:49:28Z"},
{"id":414,"date":"2014-08-07T19:35:33Z"},
{"id":415,"date":"2014-07-14T01:36:13Z"},
{"id":416,"date":"2013-12-14T03:54:55Z"},
{"id":417,"date":"2016-09-21T07:17:03Z"},
{"id":418,"date":"2014-03-25T17:54:58Z"},
{"id":419,"date":"2016-03-11T22:02:10Z"},
{"id":420,"date":"2014-12-08T00:17:43Z"},
{"id":421,"date":"2014-01-18T20:00:57Z"},
{"id":422,"date":"2013-05-16T09:53:53Z"},
{"id":423,"date":"2016-07-11T20:21:13Z"},
{"id":424,"date":"2013-06-11T10:42:14Z"},
{"id":425,"date":"2013-02-15T03:50:52Z"},
{"id":426,"date":"2014-08-29T20:23:15Z"},
{"id":427,"date":"2014-04-21T17:32:19Z"},
{"id":428,"date":"2013-10-08T11:10:32Z"},
{"id":429,"date":"2016-10-08T18:06:27Z"},
{"id":430,"date":"2016-06-12T00:19:17Z"},
{"id":431,"date":"2015-07-17T08:26:13Z"},
{"id":432,"date":"2014-06-25T17:44:53Z"},
{"id":433,"date":"2016-04-17T09:55:03Z"},
{"id":434,"date":"2015-09-08T18:25:32Z"},
{"id":435,"date":"2014-06-22T00:05:46Z"},
{"id":436,"date":"2016-06-12T22:28:38Z"},
{"id":437,"date":"2016-07-30T14:09:55Z"},
{"id":438,"date":"2014-04-23T12:04:57Z"},
{"id":439,"date":"2016-03-13T15:20:19Z"},
{"id":440,"date":"2013-02-04T02:16:54Z"},
{"id":441,"date":"2014-02-04T18:02:50Z"},
{"id":442,"date":"2014-12-11T19:29:13Z"},
{"id":443,"date":"2016-11-22T22:18:35Z"},
{"id":444,"date":"2016-04-09T17:09:08Z"},
{"id":445,"date":"2016-11-26T03:54:21Z"},
{"id":446,"date":"2016-10-18T07:50:57Z"},
{"id":447,"date":"2013-03-12T14:48:54Z"},
{"id":448,"date":"2013-02-24T19:04:56Z"},
{"id":449,"date":"2013-06-26T10:13:28Z"},
{"id":450,"date":"2013-11-27T11:29:19Z"},
{"id":451,"date":"2015-02-07T18:47:00Z"},
{"id":452,"date":"2016-04-21T07:48:21Z"},
{"id":453,"date":"2015-05-29T04:47:20Z"},
{"id":454,"date":"2016-03-06T10:57:23Z"},
{"id":455,"date":"2014-12-24T03:50:42Z"},
{"id":456,"date":"2014-08-01T21:52:52Z"},
{"id":457,"date":"2015-11-22T21:55:01Z"},
{"id":458,"date":"2013-10-26T02:54:21Z"},
{"id":459,"date":"2016-10-03T08:39:29Z"},
{"id":460,"date":"2016-10-11T16:30:39Z"},
{"id":461,"date":"2013-03-10T02:50:10Z"},
{"id":462,"date":"2016-04-14T14:53:21Z"},
{"id":463,"date":"2013-10-15T15:30:55Z"},
{"id":464,"date":"2014-04-04T20:27:01Z"},
{"id":465,"date":"2013-05-13T19:03:29Z"},
{"id":466,"date":"2016-07-16T21:10:23Z"},
{"id":467,"date":"2016-03-14T20:15:55Z"},
{"id":468,"date":"2015-10-08T23:32:45Z"},
{"id":469,"date":"2013-06-10T19:30:29Z"},
{"id":470,"date":"2013-07-05T12:38:47Z"},
{"id":471,"date":"2014-04-11T08:48:24Z"},
{"id":472,"date":"2013-11-05T15:38:22Z"},
{"id":473,"date":"2014-12-16T21:19:31Z"},
{"id":474,"date":"2016-03-02T23:58:08Z"},
{"id":475,"date":"2013-07-25T12:59:38Z"},
{"id":476,"date":"2014-06-20T05:55:05Z"},
{"id":477,"date":"2014-12-10T21:30:30Z"},
{"id":478,"date":"2016-09-18T00:14:30Z"},
{"id":479,"date":"2013-04-24T14:55:20Z"},
{"id":480,"date":"2015-01-24T22:32:08Z"},
{"id":481,"date":"2014-09-11T21:52:14Z"},
{"id":482,"date":"2015-02-27T07:57:56Z"},
{"id":483,"date":"2016-01-23T11:24:17Z"},
{"id":484,"date":"2015-12-22T12:05:32Z"},
{"id":485,"date":"2015-10-23T11:17:19Z"},
{"id":486,"date":"2013-12-26T10:41:56Z"},
{"id":487,"date":"2015-03-20T13:31:29Z"},
{"id":488,"date":"2014-10-29T11:16:21Z"},
{"id":489,"date":"2014-10-23T15:39:22Z"},
{"id":490,"date":"2014-10-12T07:36:52Z"},
{"id":491,"date":"2013-05-14T09:45:09Z"},
{"id":492,"date":"2014-12-04T22:35:15Z"},
{"id":493,"date":"2016-10-01T22:22:29Z"},
{"id":494,"date":"2015-04-14T08:20:21Z"},
{"id":495,"date":"2015-03-26T20:44:14Z"},
{"id":496,"date":"2015-08-20T22:00:29Z"},
{"id":497,"date":"2016-04-10T17:10:08Z"},
{"id":498,"date":"2015-02-02T00:30:45Z"},
{"id":499,"date":"2015-11-03T07:48:11Z"},
{"id":500,"date":"2015-01-18T18:36:29Z"},
{"id":501,"date":"2014-01-03T20:52:45Z"},
{"id":502,"date":"2014-12-09T21:22:40Z"},
{"id":503,"date":"2016-05-28T14:23:34Z"},
{"id":504,"date":"2014-10-18T13:35:55Z"},
{"id":505,"date":"2016-12-20T16:48:20Z"},
{"id":506,"date":"2014-04-13T13:09:23Z"},
{"id":507,"date":"2016-09-18T08:49:51Z"},
{"id":508,"date":"2014-10-18T01:44:13Z"},
{"id":509,"date":"2016-10-07T14:52:59Z"},
{"id":510,"date":"2014-04-05T23:13:39Z"},
{"id":663,"date":"2013-07-17T01:47:53Z"}
   ])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="testApp">
  <article ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    
    <h1>Show Only Items that are up to <span ng-bind="rule | date"></span>: (<small ng-bind="length"></small>)</h1>
    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"><strong ng-bind="($index + 1)"></strong> - <span ng-bind="item.date | date:medium"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</section>
```

Further Readings:

1. [`track by` and performances](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)
2. [Exploring `::`, one-time binding](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)

Comment: Optionally, you can move `ListData.filter(/** ... **/);` into a separate `factory` recipe.